# Why am I getting segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
int max_pairwise(int *array,int n) {
    int result=0;
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<n; i++) {
            if(array[i]*array[j]>result)
                result=array[i]*array[j];
        }
    return result;
}

int main(void) {

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int array[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);


    int result=max_pairwise(array,n);
    printf("%d",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out-of-range access will occur. Try using debugger to find it.

Comment: How about this `for(j=i+1;j<n;i++)`. What is `i++` doing there?

Comment: As a general note, it's always good to check if the pointer you're referencing is not `null` at the beginning of that function (`max_pairwise`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing the wrong variable in your inner loop:

```
//  here------v
for(j=i+1;j<n;i++)
```

As a result, `i` keeps getting incremented without bound.  This results in reading off the end of the array, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), with one of the possible symptoms being a segfault.

You want this:

```
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
```

Comment: agraahhh... thanks a lot :)

Comment: @RafiqReefat - If this solved your problem, please take time to accept the answer. That help all of us at SO as we can see the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

In function max_pairwise(), in second for loop you have typed i++, instead of j++

Comment: I don't see how your answer added any value. This was already covered 6 minutes ago by @dbush

Comment: @4386427 I don't see how your comment added any value.

Comment: @nicomp - That's sad

Comment: that wasnt covered 6 mins ago......that was posted just 10 secs before my comment